# Append Query issues

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a linked excel table that i use to create a table in my access database. I have several fields, these fields are invoice number, pallet number,  purchase order number, item number, part number, and Quantity. There are times when all those four fields have the same values for more than one record, although it doesn't happen often and we try to prevent that. I have noticed that in those situations where all the values are identical for 2 or more records, only one of these records actually gets appended to the new table. Does anyone know why this happens? My SQL code is posted below

```
INSERT INTO [Receiving Entry India] ( Invoice_No, Pallet_No, PONO, ITEMNO, Part_No, Qty )

SELECT [E-Packing list].VENDORINV, [E-Packing list].CONTAINERNo, [E-Packing list].PONO, [E-Packing list].ITEMNO, [E-Packing list].PartNo, [E-Packing list].QTYREC

FROM [E-Packing list]

GROUP BY [E-Packing list].VENDORINV, [E-Packing list].CONTAINERNo, [E-Packing list].PONO, [E-Packing list].ITEMNO, [E-Packing list].PartNo, [E-Packing list].QTYREC;
```

Comment: GROUP BY removes dupes.

Comment: Well that seemed to do it lol. I removed the whole group by statement and it appended correctly. Was it because i had a group by statement for each field?

Comment: GROUP BY will summarize your identical values into one row. It's also used when using functions such as COUNT/SUM/MAX. Google is your friend on this one.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info!